# Dynamically creating a menu of available scaffoldings in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a bunch of model classes in my Grails app, all of which are for the purpose of dynamic scaffolding of their respective database tables. For the index of the app, I'd like to have a menu of all these scaffoldings so that if a new model is added, the menu is updated.

Is there any automatic, Grails way of doing this or am I stuck with creating a naive index view with a bunch of `g:link`'s statically typed out for each class to take the user to their respective CRUD views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an extension to Joshua's answer, the following should get you a list of scaffolded controllers, in grails 3 at least.

```
<g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.findAll{ it.isReadableProperty('scaffold') } }">
    <li><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
```

EDIT

As requested in the comments, to get the table name you'll need access to the sessionFactory which you'll need to inject into a controller, something like the following will get you a map of domain name to domain table name.

Controller

```
class YourController {

    def sessionFactory

    def index() {
        def scaffoldedTables = grailsApplication.controllerClasses.findAll{ it.isReadableProperty( 'scaffold' ) }.collectEntries {
            [(it.name): sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(it.getPropertyValue( 'scaffold', Object.class )).tableName]
        }

        [scaffoldedTables: scaffoldedTables]
    }
}
```

gsp

```
<g:each var="c" in="${scaffoldedTables}">
    <li><g:link controller="${c.key}">${c.value}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Are there any additional conditions for this to work? I've tried it in a simple app with two sample scaffolded models and even though both of them have `static scaffold = [name]` in their controllers, only of them shows up in a list of links generated with the provided code :(

Comment: Sorry used find rather than findAll, try with updated example

Comment: Great, works like a charm, thanks a lot! One last question on a sidenote if I may - is there some way to diplay the name the in-Grails name translates to? I mean, if I have a scaffolded controller named `AaaBbbController`, is there any easy way to display `aaa_bbb` (or `AAA_BBB`, doesn't matter) in the generated link list as opposed to the full name that `{c.fullName}` evokes to?

Comment: You want the name of the table in the DB not the name of the domain?

Comment: Yep, so that I get a list of links in the form of `{DB_name}` as opposed to `{packageName}.{controllerName}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But should that work just as-is, simply by adding it to the `IndexController`? I need the list to be visible in the index, which is handled by the `index.gsp`, so I did `grails create-controller Index`, added the code, then added the second snippet to `views/index.gsp` but this results in no list being shown at all - it's empty. Why would that be so?

Comment: What index.gsp? there will be lots I'm guessing, do you mean the one in the root of the /grails-app/views? if so then no, it's easy enough to reroute to another controller in your UrlMappings though, something like `"/"(controller: "home")` where home is the name of your controller

Comment: Ahh, forgot to map to the controller in UrlMappings and still had a basic mapping to the index view, true that! Solved, thanks a lot for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just simply build a list of them like this:

```
<ul>
    <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
    <li><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link></li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

This code was taken from an old Grails 1.3x project from the default `index.gsp`. Not sure if it still works in recent versions of Grails, but it should at least give you an idea of what you can do that would be dynamic.

**UPDATE**
As Jeff Scott Brown has pointed out this will include *ALL* controllers, scaffolded or not, and those provided by plugins as well. In theory you could further filter the resulting classes from `grailsApplication.controllerClasses`, inspecting them for their package (assuming your domain is in a known package or packages) and/or if they are scaffolded (`static scaffold = true`).

Comment: Note that the suggested solution there is going to render more than all of the scaffolded controllers.  That code is going to list every controller, scaffolded or not, and will include controllers provided by plugins, not just controllers related to model classes in the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!